# How to revert back from current working directory in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I need some help in writing a batch file.

In my file, `file.bat`, I have this:

```
SET path = "%CD%/../file.txt"
```

I am trying to go back one folder from the current working directory.

To be more understandable, my batch file is inside, `C:/users/xy/xfolder/batfolder/file.bat`, so I want to revert back to the `C:/users/xy/xfolder`.

I've tried using `popd`, or `pushd`, but neither works, (for me to revert back one folder.

How can I set `path` to go back one folder from the current working directory of the batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: **DO NOT** use `path` as a variable name. `%path%` is a system variable that tells Windows where to find it's executables. Don't mess with it unless you know exactly what you do. Choose another name instead.

Second: your `set` syntax defines a variable `%path %`, and it's value starts with `<space>"<space>C:\...`. And the correct path delimiter is a backslash, not a slash. Best, use this syntax: `set "mypath=%cd%\..\file.txt"`
`%cd%` is the "current working directory", which may or may not be identical with the "folder where the batch file is stored"

Third: the "folder, where your batch file is", is referenced as `%~dp0`, so your desired file should be `"%~dp0..\file.txt"`, where `%~dp0` = "folder, where the batch file is stored", `..` = "one folder up" and `file.txt` = "your desired file" (this is called a "relative path").
the "Folder where `file.txt` is stored, is just `"%~dp0.."`